# MVC Razor view --- datetime display

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a below code where am fetching the time form DB and displaying in my view through model

```
 <div class="comment_time">@item.dTime</div>
```

I want to show the DateTime in user friendly way. so if keep a function in my project to do the conversion how can i call this in my .cshtml and dispaly.

for you second answer with Annotation in my scenario

```
foreach (var item in Model.lstCommet)
   {
 <div class="comment_body">@item.comments</div> 
  <div class="comment_time">@item.dTime</div>
    }
```

how do i use `displayfor` inside the lstcomment list as per ur answer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div class="comment_time">@item.dTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</div>
```

and if you wanted to call custom functions in your views, those functions have a name in ASP.NET MVC. They are called html helpers. So you could write a custom html helper:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyFunction(this HtmlHelper html, DateTime value)
    {
        return new HtmlString(value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }
}
```

and then inside your view:

```
<div class="comment_time">@Html.MyFunction(item.dTime)</div>
```

Yet another possibility is to simply decorate the property on your view model with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]]
public DateTime dTime { get; set; }
```

and then inside your view use the `DisplayFor` helper:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.dTime)
```

Comment: Awsome...Thanks. Itz a nullable field i cant overload string ?

Comment: That's one more reason to use a custom helper where you could test whether the value is not null before applying the transformation. Or simply use the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute which will handle nulls properly.

Comment: wow. 2nd one data annotation looks simple. updated my question

Comment: You should not use any foreach loops. replace your entire foreach loop with a single `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.lstCommet)`. And then write a custom display template for the corresponding type (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Commet.cshtml`) which will be strongly typed to your `Commet` model. ASP.NET MVC will then automatically call it for each element of the `lstCommet` property and inside the template you will be able to simply write `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.dTime)`.

Comment: i have placed HtmlHelperExtensions in app_code but am not able to access in view @html. Am i missing something ?

Comment: You don't need to place in in the `App_Code`. You should place this class somewhere else. For example you could have an `Extensions` folder. Also in order to use the extension in the view make sure you have brought it into scope (by adding a `@using` directive to the namespace containing your helper).

Comment: here is my another issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087175/mvc-helper-class-parameter-issue

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call `.ToString()`? You can pass the format in that you require.