# MVC helper class parameter issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have an issue in passing parameter to helper class

My model

```
public DateTime? dTime { get; set; }
```

Helper class as answered by Darin Dimitrov

```
public static IHtmlString MyFunction(this HtmlHelper html, DateTime value)
        {
            return new HtmlString(value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        }
```

and am accessing in myview to convert datetime

```
foreach (var item in Model.lstCommet)
{
 <div class="comment_time">@Html.MyFunction(item.dTime)</div>
 }
```

but am getting `"ASP.DetailPageHelper.convertTime(System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments"`

what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's a nullable type you need to reference the value.

```
foreach (var item in Model.lstCommet)
{
   <div class="comment_time">@Html.MyFunction(item.dTime.Value)</div>
}
```

You might want to run a null check as well.

```
foreach (var item in Model.lstCommet)
{
   if(item.dTime.HasValue)
   {
       <div class="comment_time">@Html.MyFunction(item.dTime.Value)</div>
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i love this portal